# Gedit's save empty file dialog I never opened

Tags: 12.04, kde, gedit, dolphin

Every time you open a text file in the file manager (Dolphin) it automatically open a blank document at the same time. The problem with that is that when i close the file it then asks to save the blank document it opened. So every time I just wanted to just view a text file I have to go through the do you want to save changes to "Untitled Document 1" dance.

Sure I can re-associate text file to launch in another editor but this must be a problem that can surely be fixed. Saw nothing in the preferences so it seems I might be stuck with the issue.

Comment: Updated to 12.10 and the problem persists. Is this a bug everyone accepts or is this a bug that is unique to myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems its a quirk of KDE, Gnome doesn't exhibit this issue at all. I have switched back to using Gnome as KDE, although a better interface, has way to many integration issues.