# GEdit runs with unsaved empty document

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gedit

In the last few days `gedit` has started behaving quite weird.

Every time I open it, it has an unsaved, empty document, even if I open some code file (so as a result, instead of opening my file `file.txt` I also have a tab with unsaved, empty file).

The error only occurs when I use the gedit from the KDE (I am using`Kubuntu`) by either double clicking the file or by "open with->gedit" command. Opening from the command line works just fine. Closing this extra tab obviously brings up the "unsaved changes" warning, and after closing - it appears again after opening file from the `KDE`.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour and if so, is there a fix?

gedit --version

```
gedit - Version 3.6.2
```

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
```

Comment: Its a bug in KDE: [#276103](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276103) and for root users LP [#793076](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/796076). See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208350/gedits-save-empty-file-dialog-i-never-opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case Gedit seems to display data from stdin in a new "Unsaved document". To break the opened pipe:

> right click the Kmenu button -> edit applications -> find gedit there
>   (for me that is "utilities") -> put `gedit $1 < /dev/null` in gedit
>   command field -> save

Source: [Gedit opening an “Unsaved document” on opening files with mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15267/gedit-opening-an-unsaved-document-on-opening-files-with-mouse).

Comment: great! what about using "gedit $1 < /dev/null %U"  ?